# Undocumented Exchange ActiveSync status while syncing

Tags: python, exchange-server, activesync, wbxml

I'm trying to build a simple Exchange ActiveSync client.

I'm using a simple Python script that sends an initial sync email command, while connecting to an Exchange 2010 SP1 .

In the request body I'm send the following XML encoded as WBXML (using pywbxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE AirSync PUBLIC "-//AIRSYNC//DTD AirSync//EN" "http://www.microsoft.com/">
<Sync>
  <Collections>
    <Collection>
      <Class>Email</Class>
      <SyncKey>0</SyncKey>
      <CollectionId>5</CollectionId>
    </Collection>
  </Collections>
</Sync>
```

The server answers with a `200 OK` but returns a `Status code: 4`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE AirSync PUBLIC "-//AIRSYNC//DTD AirSync//EN" "http://www.microsoft.com/">
<Sync>
  <Status>4</Status>
</Sync>
```

I couldn't find any documentation on this status code in the official docs. How can I figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The `Sync` status code value `4` represents a client protocol error. It is documented on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675457%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx).

A correct `Sync` command would look more like the following, assuming that `Inbox` has an ID of 5 (converted from WBXML to a readable XML):

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<Sync>
  <Collections>
    <Collection>
      <SyncKey>0</SyncKey>
      <CollectionId>5</CollectionId>
      <Options>
        <FilterType>5</FilterType>
        <BodyPreference>
          <Type>1</Type>
          <TruncationSize>32768</TruncationSize>
        </BodyPreference>
      </Options>
    </Collection>
  </Collections>
</Sync>
```

The EAS protocol requires that you `Provision` and `FolderSync` first, however. You can't just jump straight to a `Sync`. The basic protocol sequence is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee238029%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx).